# Binomial coefficients inequation problem

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients, factorial

Can anyone help me solve this:
$$5\binom{13}{x} < \binom{x + 2}{4}$$
After turning it to factorial I don't know what to do nothing seems to cancel out. $x$ is a positive integer.
I end up with this when trying to solve it:
$$\frac{13!}{x(x+1)(13 - x)!} < \frac{(x+2)!}{5!}$$
Edit: I found solutions in a book with this task, says solutions are {11, 12, 13} I've plugged them in and they seem to work. But can anyone explain how it was solved?

Comment: Can you post what you have after turning into factorial form?

Comment: For $x>13$, the L.H.S. is zero. The statement is false for $x=1,2,3,4,5,6$

Answer (score 1):

$x>10$.  I got this simply by plugging in all the values of x from 2 to 13.

Here is the Mathematica code and output I wrote:

```
Do[Print[5*13!/(x!*(13 - x)!) - (x + 2)!/(4!*(x + 2 - 4)!)], {x, 2, 13}]

389
1425
3560
6400
8510
8454
6225
3245
935
-325
-936
-1360
```

Comment: But that's guessing and x = 14 makes you end up with (13 - 14)!

Comment: 13 choose x is not defined for x>13.  And no, writing a program to test all the possible solutions is not "guessing".

Comment: It is reasonably standard to define $n \choose x$  for **all** natural numbers $n$ and $x$, with value $0$ if $x > n$.  In that case all integers $x > 10$ are solutions.

Answer (score -1):

$$5\binom{13}{x} < \binom{x + 2}{4}$$
can be seen as:
\begin{align}
5 \, \frac{13!}{x! \, (13-x)!} &< \frac{(x+2)!}{4! \, (x-2)!} \\
5! \, 13! \, (x-2)! &< x! \, (13-x)! \, (x+2)! \\  
5! \, 13! \, x! &< x(x-1) \, x! \, (x+2)! \, (13-x)! \\
5! \, 13! &< x(x-1) \, (x+2)! \, (13-x)! 
\end{align}
From this can be stated that, for $x$ being an integer, $2 \leq x \leq 13$ for allowable values. Note that by inspection the right-hand binomial limits the value of $x$ to $x \leq 13$. The right-hand binomial provides the lower limit $x \geq 2$. By utilizing the allowable values of $x$ it is seen that the values $x \in \{11, 12, 13\}$ are valid solutions.

Comment: I tried x = 5, you end up with : 128700 < 35

Comment: @user1949350 The posted result does not include $x=5$, but rather restricts $x$ as $11$, $12$, and $13$.  +1 for the correct result.